# Dragging from desktop to air application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I have been looking all over the internet and I can't find any good (or recent) example from a air application where an image (for example) is dragged from the desktop in the application.

The only example I could find is this:
http://blog.everythingflex.com/2007/06/18/simple-drag-and-drop-air/

The problem is that flashbuilder gives errors on:
import flash.desktop.DragActions;
import flash.desktop.TransferableData;
import flash.desktop.TransferableFormats;
import flash.desktop.DragManager;
(and this are only the errors at the import section)

I know this last one can be replaced by mx.managers.DragManager, but this is another class since than I get errors on "DragManager.acceptDragDrop" for example...

Does anyone know a good (and recent = one that will work with flashbuilder 4.5) example, or can anyone give me information about dragging images to a air application?

greets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try these links : 
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/07/air-example-native-drag-and-drop/ 
http://www.spltech.co.uk/blog/adobe-air/native-drag-and-drop-in-adobe-air-with-example

Comment: Thanks! the second link was the thing I was looking for :) its a nice example to start from